# Chart.js: Legend doesn't update on first call to chart.update()

Tags: chart.js

I'm having trouble updating the legend in chart.js.

[Here's a sandbox to follow along.](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-elgamal-nosqo)

I have a standard bar chart with two data points per label, such as:

```
let chartData = {
  apple: {
    a: 1,
    b: 3
  },
  orange: {
    a: 2,
    b: 2
  },
  banana: {
    a: 3,
    b: 1
  }
};
```

[image: Example Bar Chart]

On button click, the sort is changed from a->b or the reverse.

The *colors also change* and therein lies my problem:

[image: GIF of bar chart toggle]

The legend doesn't update on the first toggle. Afterward it is always one toggle behind.

I've tried looking at how to explicitly set the colors within the legend so that I can just manually update them in the `updateChart()` function, but in the docs I only see the ability to change font color and the legend itself - not the individual label colors.

I'd prefer to not have to use custom CSS to override... Is this a bug in Chart.js? Am I performing the update incorrectly? Do I have to call generateLegend()?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is a bug in chart.js:

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7457

Evert Timberg, the creator of chart.js replied with two potential fixes:

1. Update to version v3.0.0-alpha where the bug had been fixed
2. Call chart.update() twice (which may have performance issues)

---

Both solutions are confirmed.

v3 is in alpha and has several breaking changes - so a migration from 2.x -> 3.x may take some work.

Calling chart.update() twice of course causes some performance overhead, but on smaller examples like this, it isn't at all noticeable.

Thank you to @etimberg of chart.js for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's beacause your `labels` are not sorted initially. If you sort them when assigning the data to `sortedKeys`, it will work as expected.

```
let sortedKeys = Object.keys(chartData).sort(
  (a, b) => chartData[b][sortByCol] - chartData[a][sortByCol]
);
```

Please have a look at your amended [**code sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-margulis-hevnf?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Just tried the sandbox, I still see the same issue... The maintainer of chart.js mentioned that this is an actual bug in chart.js which has been fixed in the new version alpha 3: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7457